# A bound on number of divisors of $n$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, factoring

Let $n$ be a positive number. I want to bound the number of divisors of $n$. Let $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$. Let $n = p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_r^{e_r} $ be the prime factorization of $n$. then

$$d(n) = (e_1 +1)(e_2 +1)\cdots (e_r +1)$$

we can see that $e_i + 1 \le 2^{e_i}$

I don't know how to proceed i.e to prove $d(n) <  2^{(1 + \epsilon) \log n/ \log \log n}$ for $\epsilon$ greater than zero. Is there exist a better bound?

Comment: Proceed to what?

Comment: You want to bound the divisors : do you want a bound completely in terms of $n$ and not depending on stray terms?

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг I have edite the question

Comment: Roughly speaking, we have particularly many divisors when $n$ is the product of $r$ distinct small primes. One can argue that $p_r\sim \log n$ and that there are $\sim\frac{p_r}{\log p_r}$ primes below $p_r$, so $r\sim\frac{log n}{\log \log n}$ ...

Comment: [Wikipedia on highly composite numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number) gives a formula for $Q(x)$, the number of highly composite numbers below $x$.  I haven't easily found an asymptotic formula for the $n$th highly composite number, but maybe you can look where $Q(x) $ increases by $1$

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen how can you conclude that r~$\frac {log n}{log log n} $?

Comment: @RossMillikan  reults of Nicolas and/or Robin summarized in http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added: the first inequality is not tied to $\log 2$ well enough. The second one, from Robin's dissertation, does give
$$  \frac{\log d(n)}{\log 2} \leq  \left( \frac{\log n}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1.934850967971...}{\log \log n} \right)$$

---

With equality at $n = 6983776800 = 2^5 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19$ and $d(n) = 2304,$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1.5379398606751... \right)} =  n^{ \left( \frac{1.0660186782977...}{\log \log n} \right) }. $$ Full details of the proof appear in J.-L. Nicolas et G. Robin. *Majorations explicites pour le nombre de diviseurs de n*, Canad. Math. Bull., 26, 1983, 485--492. The next two appear in the dissertation of Robin.

With equality at a number $n$ near $6.929 \cdot 10^{40},$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1.934850967971...}{\log \log n} \right)}.   $$ Compare this one with Theorem 317 in Hardy and Wright, attributed to Wigert (1907),
$$ \limsup \frac{\log d(n)  \log \log n}{\log n} = \log 2.  $$

With equality at a number $n$ near $3.309 \cdot 10^{135},$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1}{\log \log n} + \frac{4.762350121177...}{\left(\log \log n \right)^2} \right)}   $$