# Has $\sigma\left(\sigma_0(n)^4\right)=n$ infinitely many solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

In this post, for integers $n\geq 1$ we consider the sum of divisors function $\sum_{d\mid n}d$ denoted as $\sigma(n)$ and the divisor-counting function $\sum_{d\mid n}1$ as $\sigma_0(n)$. Then I wondered about the solutions of $$\sigma\left((\sigma_0(n))^4\right)=n.\tag{1}$$

Here is the Wikipedia's article [*Divisor function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) dedicated to the sum of the positive divisors of an integer $n\geq 1$, that is $\sigma(n)$ and the arithmetic function $\sigma_0(n)$ (also denoted in the literature as $\tau(n)$) that counts the number of those positive divisors.

I was inspired in [1].

> **Question.** Can you prove or refute that there exist infinitely many solutions $n\geq 1$ of $$\sigma\left((\sigma_0(n))^4\right)=n\,?$$ **Many thanks.**

**Computational evidence.** Using a Pari/GP program I know that the first few solutions of previous equation $\sigma\left(\sigma_0(n)^4\right)=n,$ are $$1 ,31 ,121 ,511, 3751$$ and $61831.$ Thus I've no enough computational evidence showing that maybe should be infinitely many solutions of $(1)$. Finally seems that previous sequence isn't in the OEIS.

### References:

[1] *Problem 3565*, Crux Mathematicorum, Volume 37, Number 6 (2011).

Comment: Since $\sigma$ is multiplicative function, the product of two relatively prime solutions is also solution. For example, $31 \times 121=3751$. However, I feel like there are only finite number of solutions...

Comment: I think that also there are only a finite number of solutions ( and I know that 
my words contradict my conjecture, but my computations don't offer me more), I tried to combine the size of the divisor-counting function and inequalities from the literature about the maximal size of the sum of divisors function @didgogns , but my attempt was failed.

Comment: By the way, what was the original Problem 3565, Crux Mathematicorum, Volume 37, Number 6?

Comment: Many thanks @didgogns again for your new calculations, 
your work was a professional work $100$% and thanks to the user editing the post. On the other hand you can see it from the web of Crux Mathematicorum, choose the Volume **37** (that is the year 2011)> **Oct** > *Solutions*... Feel free to study equations that can be stated as generalization, I am an amateur and I cann't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sigma_0(n)=m$, and we need to solve the following equation:$$\sigma_0(\sigma(m^4))=m$$
with known solutions $m=1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12$. We have a good estimation on the upper bound of both $\sigma_0$ and $\sigma$ functions. [For $\sigma_0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635537/a-bound-on-number-of-divisors-of-n), $\sigma_0(x)\le x^{ \left( \frac{1.07}{\log \log x} \right) }$ and [for $\sigma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Growth_rate), $\sigma(x)<e^\gamma x\ln \ln x+\frac{0.6483x}{\ln \ln x}$ ($\gamma$ is Euler-Mascheroni constant). For sufficiently large $x$ (at least $e^{e^{5}}$), $\sigma(x)<x^{1.1}$ and $\sigma_0(x)\le x^{0.214}$, therefore$$\sigma_0(\sigma(x^4))<\sigma_0(x^{4.4})\le x^{0.9416}<x$$
so there is only finite number of solution.

---

**Edit June 6**

I'll retry using a better upper bound, $\sigma_0(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1.935}{\log \log n} \right)}$. Indeed, if $x>e^{e^{4.4}/4.4}$, then again$$\sigma_0(\sigma(x^4))<\sigma_0(x^{4.4})\le x^{0.9979}<x$$so we need to check only for $x<e^{e^{4.4}/4.4}\approx1.1\times10^8$. For such $x$, $\ln(\ln(x^4))<4.3047$ and so $\sigma(x^4)<4.3047e^\gamma x^4+\frac{0.6483x^4}{4.3047}<7.8176x^4<1.1245\times10^{33}$. Now I hope I could get a better upper bound for $\sigma_0(\sigma(x^4))$ using the fact that $\sigma(x^4)$ is odd number, but there is no researches available and the numerical result (https://oeis.org/A053624) is also limited to like $30$ digits.

Therefore, I bruted forced to find that odd number under $1.1245\times10^{33}$ can have at most $11796480$ divisors. It again gives maximum $\sigma(x^4)$ value of about $1.4706\times10^{29}$, which gives maximum divisor number of $2654208$, which gives maximum $\sigma(x^4)$ value of $3.6857\times10^{26}$, which gives maximum divisor number of $983040$, which gives maximum $\sigma(x^4)$ value of $6.8223\times10^{24}$, which gives maximum divisor number of $497664$, which gives maximum $\sigma(x^4)$ value of $4.4271\times10^{23}$, which gives maximum divisor number of $307200$, which gives maximum $\sigma(x^4)$ value of $6.3697\times10^{22}$, which gives maximum divisor number of $221184$, which gives maximum $\sigma(x^4)$ value of $1.7009\times10^{22}$, which gives maximum divisor number of $184320$, which gives maximum $\sigma(x^4)$ value of $8.1725\times10^{21}$, which gives maximum divisor number of $153600$, which gives maximum $\sigma(x^4)$ value of $3.9265\times10^{21}$, which gives maximum divisor number of $138240$, which gives maximum $\sigma(x^4)$ value of $2.5706\times10^{21}$, which gives maximum divisor number of $122880$. That is, $m \le 122880$.

Also, $2.5706\times10^{21}<3^{45}$ so $m$ cannot have prime factor greater than $45$. Computer-checking all integers under $122880$ confirms that they are indeed the only solutions.

Comment: You have magic in your soccer boots! Many thanks I am going to study it, and the linked MSE and Wikipedia. On the other hand $4.4\cdot 0.214$ was close to $1$. If you want to add some observation/calculation in next future feel free to do it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why  $n=\sigma(m^4)$ is equivalent to the statement $\sigma_0(\sigma(m^4))=m$ ? I would think you'd need $\sigma_0$ to be injective for that to be true :)

Comment: From the original equation, applying $\sigma_0$ to both side gives $\sigma_0(\sigma\left((\sigma_0(n))^4\right))=\sigma_0(n)$ so $\sigma_0(\sigma(m^4))=m$ is derived. From $\sigma_0(\sigma(m^4))=m$, $4$-power both sides and applying $\sigma$ gives $\sigma(\sigma_0(\sigma(m^4))^4)=\sigma(m^4)$ so original equation is derived.