# What positive integer $n$ maximizes the function $f(n) = \sigma_0(n)/n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A friend and I were having a discussion on which base would be best. I argued that 12 would be the best because it has the most divisors relative to its size. However, I'm not sure that 12 is actually the number that maximizes this ratio. To investigate, I formalized my observation by claiming that 12 maximizes the function $f(z) = \sigma_0(z)/z$ where $\sigma_0(n) = \sum_{d|n} d^0$ is the function which counts the divisors of $n$. I found some articles and some interesting properties of $\sigma_0$ but nothing which I was able to use to prove this property. I'm not too familiar with this kind of thing so I wasn't sure exactly how to go about it.

Does anyone have any idea as to how one could prove this? Right now, it seems like the formula which would be most useful would be that $$\sigma_o(n) = \Pi_{i = 1}^{\omega(n)}(1 - a_i)$$ where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $b$ so that $n = \Pi_{i = 1}^{\omega(n)}p_i^{a_i}$.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: On thinking about it a little more, it seems like 12 definitely does not maximize this. For example, 6 has 4 divisors whereas 12 has 6 of them. As a commenter also pointed out, 3 has 2 divisors. The best does seem to be 2, though, with two divisors. If $\sigma_0(n) = n$, then for all $m \leq n$, we would have that $m|n$. That would imply that every prime less than $n$ would be included in the prime factorization of $n$. This is a fairly strong property that I suspect only 2 holds.

Comment: $\frac {\sigma_0(3)}3=\frac 23$, $\frac {\sigma_0(4)}{4}=\frac 34$,  $\frac {\sigma_0(12)}{12}=\frac 12$.

Comment: $\sigma_0(n)/n$ is multiplicative. $\sigma_0(p^k)/p^k = (k+1)/p^k < 1$ for all $p^k > 2$. Otherwise simply find the integers $n$ such that every integer in $[1,n]$ is a divisor. In particular, if $n\ne 1$ then $n-1$ divides $n$.

Comment: It should be easy to show that $\frac 34$ is the max.  After all, for any $n$ we know that none of the integers $m$ with $\frac n2<m<n$ can be divisors of $n$ and for large $n$ that block contains  about $\frac n2$ integers. All you need is for that block to exceed $\frac n4$.   So there are only finitely many $n$ to test.

Comment: I thought that the maximum is achieved for $n=2$, since $$\frac{\sigma_0 (2)}{2}=1$$

Comment: @Crostul  Ah, well true.  I started at $n=3$ to avoid those cases but I agree that nothing in the post should rule out $n=1$ or $n=2$.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks! I hadn't thought of these clear counterexamples to my claim. I bet that 2 maximizes it and proving that would be substantially easier I think. I doubt $\sigma_0(n) = n$ holds for many integers $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $\displaystyle \frac{\sigma_0(n)}{n} = \prod_p \frac{\alpha_p+1}{p^{\alpha_p}}$ where $\alpha_p \ge 0$.

But $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha_p+1}{p^{\alpha_p}} < 1$ for all prime $p$ and all $\alpha >0$ with the only exception of $p = 2$ and $\alpha = 1$, which means that the maximum is achieved when all the $\alpha$'s are $0$ ($n = 1$) or when all but $\alpha_2$ are $0$ and $\alpha_2 = 1$ (n = 2).

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635537/a-bound-on-number-of-divisors-of-n), we know that

$$\sigma_0(n)\leq n^{\frac{1.0660186782977...}{\log \log n}}<n^{ \frac{2}{\log \log n}}$$

(with equality at $n=6983776800$). This then implies that

$$\frac{\sigma_0(n)}{n}<n^{ \frac{2}{\log \log n}-1}$$

Now, it is easy to see that for $n\geq 1619$ we have

$$\frac{2}{\log \log n}-1<0$$

Then for $n\geq 1619$ we know

$$\frac{\sigma_0(n)}{n}<n^{ \frac{2}{\log \log n}-1}<n^0=1$$

But

$$\frac{\sigma_0(1)}{1}=\frac{\sigma_0(2)}{2}=1$$

Now, we only have to check all integers $3\leq n\leq 1618$. These are easily checked and we conclude that the function is maximized at $n\in\{1,2\}$.

---

EDIT: If you wanted the case $n\geq 3$, then in much the same manner we see that for $n\geq 2880$ we have

$$n^{\frac{2}{\log \log n}-1}<\frac{3}{4}$$

Then after checking all integers $5\leq n\leq 2879$ we may conclude that the function is maximized at $n=4$ where

$$\frac{\sigma_0(4)}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: This is a HUGE overkill.

Comment: Yes, but this method can be broadened to find the maximum for $n\geq N$ for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ (see the edit)

Comment: @jjagmath  the relevant point from Ramanujan's method is that there is a nontrivial maximum for $\frac{\sigma_0(n)}{n^\delta}$   for real $0 < \delta < 1 .$   For $\delta \geq 1$ the maximum occurs at $n=1$ This construction leads to the Superior Highly Composite Numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number   Fairly good answer at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43103/what-is-the-lower-bound-for-highly-composite-numbers

Comment: The OP is struggling with a very elementary problem from basic number theory, i think it's not a good idea give an answer that involve much more advanced inequalities and methods.

Comment: @WillJagy By the way, my answer (that is elementary) can also be generalized. Analysing the maximum of $\frac{\alpha + 1}{p^{\alpha \delta}}$ is what gives the result from the page on mathoverflow you posted.